# How can I implement android studio shortcuts to visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, editor

I want to implement of all android studio shortcuts to visual studio, I searched about it a lot and I readed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019) tutorial but this tutorial Says: **Select Tools > Import and Export Settings from the menu bar to open the Import and Export Settings Wizard.**
But my visual studio doesn't have tools button,[image]

Information about my visual studio:

Version: 1.38.1 (user setup)

Commit: b37e54c98e1a74ba89e03073e5a3761284e3ffb0

Date: 2019-09-11T13:35:35.387Z

Electron: 4.2.10

Chrome: 69.0.3497.128

Node.js: 10.11.0

V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0

OS: Windows_NT ia32 6.1.7601

Please help me I want to implement android studio shortcuts to visual studio, Thanks (-;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to extensions and search for intellij.
It will show intellij shortcuts for vs code. Install it and done.